# CSS3 animation is not working

Tags: css, svg, cross-browser, css-animations

I have created an animation for SVG using css3  which is working perfectly in Chrome and Firefox. It is partially working in Safari but not working in Internet Explorer (IE9+ which support css animations)

[**See Demo**](http://codepen.io/ahsanrathore/pen/BbArn)

**CSS:**

```
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  70%,80% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill-opacity: 0;
  }

  85% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }

  95% {
    stroke: #17739D;
    stroke-dashoffset: -301;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-dashoffset: -301;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes dash {
  70%,80% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill-opacity: 0;
  }

  85% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }

  95% {
    stroke: #17739D;
    stroke-dashoffset: -301;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-dashoffset: -301;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes dash {
  70%,80% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill-opacity: 0;
  }

  85% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }

  95% {
    stroke: #17739D;
    stroke-dashoffset: -301;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-dashoffset: -301;
  }
}


@keyframes dash {
  70%,80% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill-opacity: 0;
  }

  85% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }

  95% {
    stroke: #17739D;
    stroke-dashoffset: -301;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-dashoffset: -301;
  }
}

#Layer_1 { 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right : auto;  
    top: 50%; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 50%; 
    margin-left: -65px; 
    margin-top: -35px;   
}

svg {
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
}

svg * {
  stroke: #666;
  #stroke: #17739D;
  stroke-width: 1;
  fill-opacity: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 350;
  stroke-dashoffset: 440;
}

svg #bp_svg * {

  -webkit-animation-name : dash;
  -moz-animation-name : dash;
  -ms-animation-name : dash;
  animation-name : dash;

  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 4s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-duration: 4s;

  -webkit-animation-timing-function : linear;
  -moz-animation-timing-function : linear;
  -ms-animation-timing-function : linear;
  animation-timing-function : linear;

  -webkit-animation-fill-mode : forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode : forwards;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode : forwards;
  animation-fill-mode : forwards;
}
```

Can anyone help me to sort out what to do to make it work properly in Safari and IE also?

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with your code or if this information is helpful to you, but after an hour of cracking your code, **I am able to display it without animation in IE**.
I changed the `fill-opacity` in the CSS block `svg *`. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c87vY/4/)

Comment: This seems like an ideal fallback as the animation is icing and you really just need to see the cake.

Comment: +1 because the animation is cool :)

Comment: "The easiest way to animate SVG is using CSS animations or transitions. The downside is it doesn't work in IE, if you want IE support you'll need to use requestAnimationFrame and update the values frame by frame with script." ref: http://jakearchibald.com/2013/animated-line-drawing-svg/

Comment: @ChrisHardie Post as an answer

Answer (score 3):

While CSS3 animations are supported in IE9, SVG animations are not even supported in IE11 and it's hard to tell whether they will ever be. You probably have to either rely on animated HTML elements or use JavaScript which will not benefit from the hardware acceleration used to render CSS animations but still might be a viable solution.

Another idea would be to prerender it and deploy it as a gif, either every time or only in IE.

Source: http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-smil

Comment: The OP is not using SMIL animations though, but css3 animations: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 animations are not supported in IE9, which explains why it doesn't work in IE9. The same will apply for Safari,it may help to also give the versions of each browser. Please refer to this list of supported features: http://caniuse.com/css-animation

Comment: Morgan, Ok I agree that it is not supported in IE9 but it should work for IE10+ and safari

Comment: What versions though? You aren't saying what version of Safari. I saw it working partially in version 5.1.7. I recreated your animaiton locally yesterday and could have sworn it worked in IE10. Just checked and d'oh!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using raphaeljs javascript library. It has great capability in animating svg.

> Raphael currently supports Chrome 5.0+ Firefox 3.0+, Safari 3.0+,
>   Opera 9.5+ and Internet Explorer 6.0+

http://raphaeljs.com/

http://raphaeljs.com/playground.html - quick preview.