# SVG spinner isn't showing up on IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, animation, svg

I am using the material spinner from this codepen: https://codepen.io/mrrocks/pen/EiplA

It displays perfectly in all browsers except IE.

Here is the SVG icon:

```
<svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <circle class="path" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle>
</svg>
```

Then we have the LESS to make it rotate and all that:

```
$offset: 187;
$duration: 1.4s;

.spinner {
  animation: rotator $duration linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotator {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(270deg); }
}

.path {
  stroke-dasharray: $offset;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  transform-origin: center;
  animation:
    dash $duration ease-in-out infinite, 
    colors ($duration*4) ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes colors {
    0% { stroke: #4285F4; }
    25% { stroke: #DE3E35; }
    50% { stroke: #F7C223; }
    75% { stroke: #1B9A59; }
  100% { stroke: #4285F4; }
}

@keyframes dash {
 0% { stroke-dashoffset: $offset; }
 50% {
   stroke-dashoffset: $offset/4;
   transform:rotate(135deg);
 }
 100% {
   stroke-dashoffset: $offset;
   transform:rotate(450deg);
 }
}
```

As far as I can tell everything I am using seems to be supported in IE11 according to caniuse.com: http://caniuse.com/#search=svg and http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation.

I tried adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` but it had no effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: css variables are not supported. Use the DOM Explorer tab of the dev tool to confirm that the style rules are applied to an element. Use the dev tool of your chrome browser to determine which UserAgent style rules for chrome are applied... transform-origin and others need to be declared in a css reset section in your stylesheets so that all browsers use the same userAgent or userStylesheet defaults.

Comment: It's compiled before use, as should be obvious if you looked at the codepen. Also this isn't a chrome issue so using the chrome inspect element is useless..

Comment: see answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302615/css3-animation-is-not-working